# only jpg jpeg and .... photos should be uploaded

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I've been trying to solve this problem for several hours, but it didn't work.

The problem is:

I only want to upload photos such as jpg png, but when I upload photos with this type, I get the error message that should only be displayed if the type of uploaded data is wrong.

I wrote all the code, and I also wrote some parts of the code where the problem might be, sSo that everything is clear for you.

```
<?php

//msg for the first name,
$msg='';
//msg2 for the last name
$msg2='';

//msg3 for the email
$msg3='';
//msg4 for the date
$msg4='';
//msg5 for the password
$msg5='';
//msg6 for the re Password 
$msg6='';
//msg7 for the image
$msg7='';
//msg8 for the checkbox
$msg8='';
$msg9='';
$msg10='';

$firstname='';$lastname='';$email='';$date='';$password='';$c_password='';$image='';

include("includes\header.php");
include("includes\config.php");

/**isset: checks if a variable is set, which means that it has to be declared and is not NULL */
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//mysqli not mysql`enter code here 
$firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
$lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mail']);
$date=$_POST['dob'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];
$c_password=$_POST['cpass'];
$image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$checkbox=isset($_POST['check']);

// this two line was for testin, if all this is ok 
//echo $firstname. "<br>".$lastname."<br>"."<br>".$email."<br>". "<br>".$date."<br>". "<br>".$password."<br>"
//."<br>".$c_password."<br>"."<br>".$image."<br>"."<br>".$checkbox."<br>";

//strlen is to returns the length of the string(firstname)
if(strlen($firstname) <3)
{
    // This message must be displayed if the number of letters of the given name is less than 3
    $msg="<div class='error'>First name must contain atleast 3 characters</div>";
}

else if(strlen($lastname) <3)
{
        // This message must be displayed if the number of letters of the given lastname is less than 3
    $msg2="<div class='error'>Last name must contain atleast 3 characters</div>";
}

//filter_var: filters the email with  FVE.
else if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
        // This message must be displayed if the number of letters of the given lastname is less than 3
    $msg3="<div class='error'>Enter Vaild Email</div>";
}

else if (empty($date))
{
$msg4="<div class='error'> Please Enter Your Date of Birth</div>";
}

else if (empty($password))
{
    $msg5="<div class='error'> Please Enter Your Password </div>";

}
else if (strlen($password) <5)
{

 $msg5="<div class='error'>Password must contain atleast 5 Character</div>" ;   

}

else if ($password!==$c_password)
{

    $msg6="<div class='error'> Password is not same </div>";
}

else if ($image=='')
{

    $msg7="<div class='error'> Please Upload Your Profile Image </div>";
}

else if($checkbox=='')
{
$msg8="<div class='error'> Please Agree Our Termas an Conditions </div>";
}
 
else
{

    $img_ext=explode(".",$image);
    $image_ext=$img_ext['1'];
    if($image_ext=='jpg' || $image_ext=='png' || $image_ext=='PNG' || $image_ext=='JPG' || $image_ext=='jpeg' || $image_ext=='JPEG' )
    {
        
        // to conection to the  database and gives the values    
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,mail,password,dob,img)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname','$email','$date','$password','$image')");

        $msg9="<div class='success'> You are Successfully Registered </div>";
        $firstname='';$lastname='';$email='';$date='';$password='';$c_password='';$image='';
    }

        else
           {
           $msg7="<div class='error'> Please Upload an Image File</div>";
           }

     }

// this slash  is from the if sumbmit
}

?>

//this part of code is  from body

</head>
<style>
</style>    
 <body>
     <!-- container: to set the content's margins dealing with the responsive behaviors of the layout.-->
 <div class='container'>
        <div class='login-form col-md-4 offset-md-4'>

                <!--jumbotron: ndicates a big box for calling extra attention to.-->
                <div class='jumbotron' style='margin-top:40px; padding-top:20px;   background-color:00FF00;   font-size: 20px; width:450px'> 
                    <h3 align='center'>SignUp</h3><br> 
                    <?php echo $msg9;?><br>

                    <!-- form: to creat form for user input
                        method=”POST” Specifying a value of POST means the browser will send the data to the web server to be processed.            
                        
                        enctype: specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server:
                            
                    -->
                    <form method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label> First Name: </label>

                            <!-- 1name: the name of th input
                                 2. placeholder: specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of a input field / textarea.
                                 3. All textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select> elements with class .form-control have a width of 100%.
                            -->
                            <input type='text' name='fname' placeholder="First Name" class='form-control' value='<?php echo $firstname;?>'>
                            <!--IF the type of information provided is not the required one, this message will be displayed-->

                            <?php echo $msg;?>
                            
                        <!--the end of the div of First Name-->
                        </div>

                        <!--start div of the Last Name-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label> Last Name: </label>
                            <input type='text' name='lname' placeholder="Last Name" class='form-control'  value='<?php echo $lastname;?>'>
                          <!--IF the type of information provided is not the required one, this message will be displayed-->

                            <?php echo $msg2;?>

                            <!--the end of the div of the Last Name-->
                        </div>
                    
                          <!--start div of the Email-->
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label> Email: </label>
                            <input type='email' name='mail' placeholder="Your Email" class='form-control' value='<?php echo $email;?>'>

                            <!--IF the type of information provided is not the required one, this message will be displayed-->
                            <?php echo $msg3;?>

                            <!--the end of the div of the Email-->
                        </div>

                          <!--start div of the birth day-->
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label> Date of Birth: </label>
                            <input type='date' name='dob'  value='<?php echo $date;?>'>
                            <?php echo $msg4; ?>

                            <!--the end of the div of birth day-->
                         </div>

                          <!--start div of the Password-->
                           <div class="form-group">
                                 <label> Password: </label>
                                 <input type='password' name='pass' placeholder="Password" class='form-control' value='<?php echo $password;?>'>
                                 <?php echo $msg5;?>

                              <!--the end of the div of the Password-->
                             </div>

                                <!--start div of the Re-enter Password-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                 <label> Re-enter Password: </label>
                                                <input type='password' name='cpass' placeholder="Re-enter Password" class='form-control' value='<?php echo $c_password;?>'>
                                                <?php echo $msg6;?>
                                        <!--the end of the div of the Re-enter Password-->
                                     </div>
                  
                                          <!--start div of the image profile  -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                 <label> Profile Image: </label>
                                                <input type='file' name='image'  value='<?php echo $image;?>'/><br>
                                                <?php  echo $msg7;?>

                                                <?php  echo $msg10;?>
                                        <!--the end of the div of the image profile -->
                                     </div>
                                    

                                  <!--start div of the checkbox  -->
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                                 <input type='checkbox' name='check'  />
                                                I Agree the terms and conditions
                                                <?php  echo $msg8;?>


                                        <!--the end of the div of the checkbox -->
                                     </div>

                                        <!-- submit button-->
                                     <br><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'  class='btn btn-success' style="background-color:blue;"><br>

                           <!--the end of the form for the sign up icon-->          
                        </form>

                   <!--the end of the jumbtorn class-->     
                 </div>
   
        </div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

I have rewritten the part of the code here where the problem could be.

```
 // this part is from php
else
{

    $img_ext=explode(".",$image);
    $image_ext=$img_ext['1'];
    if($image_ext=='jpg' || $image_ext=='png' || $image_ext=='PNG' || $image_ext=='JPG' || $image_ext=='jpeg' || $image_ext=='JPEG' )
    {
        
        // to conection to the  database and gives the values    
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,mail,password,dob,img)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname','$email','$date','$password','$image')");

        $msg9="<div class='success'> You are Successfully Registered </div>";
        $firstname='';$lastname='';$email='';$date='';$password='';$c_password='';$image='';
    }

        else
           {
           $msg7="<div class='error'> Please Upload an Image File</div>";
           }

     }
```

This part is from body.

I have rewritten the part of the code here where the problem could be.

```
          <!--start div of the image profile  -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                 <label> Profile Image: </label>
                                                <input type='file' name='image'  value='<?php echo 
                                                $image;?>'/><br>
                                                <?php  echo $msg7;?>

                                                <?php  echo $msg10;?>
                                        <!--the end of the div of the image profile -->
                                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your input `accept` parameter:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

When user choosing image he will see only JPG files in own file manager. I don't remember is that worked in every browser. In Chrome must work. In Safari maybe not.

Also you can check your file extention before send to server side. Just write custom validator like this (JS code):

```
var file = "test.mp4";
var valid = (file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("."), file.length)).toLowerCase();

if (valid != '.jpg') {
  console.log("Please Select Valid Image");
} else {
  console.log("Is valid image");
}
```

Comment: In PHP, also convert the extension to lowercase, and then check it.
`if ( ( $image_ext=="jpg") || ($image_ext=="png") || ($image_ext=="jpeg")){
    echo "GOOD";
} else { 
    echo "WRONG";
}`

Use `()` inside `if`

Comment: Check the value of $image_ext value before checking. What console say ? Maybe has some errors ?